# Excel formula for linked value as percentage

Tags: excel, formatting, formula, percentage

Excel converts a percentage to a fraction when pasted as a link, e.g. 50% in referenced cell B2 in Sheet1 is shown as 0.5 in linked cell X10 in Sheet2.

However, instead of a percentage, some linked cells in Sheet1 contain text or are empty (there are many workbooks - Sheet1 is a questionnaire).

So a formula like `=((('Sheet1'!B2)*100)& "%") & ""` does not work for all cells, because the value might be text (gives a `#VALUE` error), and also `& ""` does not work for empty cells in this formula.

I need a formula to convert the linked fractions in Sheete to percentages in Sheet2. I have tried with ISNUMBER without success and also do not know how ISNUMBER could be made to work with a text value (yet another nested IF formula, I guess).

Can anyone point to a solution?

Thanks!

CJ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if it is worth putting as an answer, but I don't see a problem with

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(Sheet1!B1),Sheet1!B1,"")
```

and format the range in Sheet2 starting with B1 as percentage with required number of decimal places.

For conditional formatting, I could only get it to work with

```
=NOT(ISNUMBER(Sheet1!B1))
```

and a format of ;;;

**EDIT**

If you want the text to appear, first formula should be

```
=IF(Sheet1!B1="","",Sheet1!B1)
```

or use ;;;@ in above formatting rule.

Comment: Hm maybe I'm confused but isn't OP only asking to just turn a number into a percentage if a number has been pasted? He doesn't seem to care if cell is either empty or textvalue.

Comment: I thought the main problem was that blanks in Sheet1 were coming through as zeroes in Sheet2, but you may be right.

Comment: Thanks, Tom! That certainly WAS worth putting as an answer - problem almost solved! Yes, the problem was also that blanks were coming through as zeroes and that's fixed, but text is not coming through.

Comment: @TomSharpe and @cdfj. A efficient way to hide a 0 would be through custom formatting the cell with `0;-0;;@`

Comment: Thanks `0;-0;;@` - got that! But still no text!

Comment: I think if you try my conditional formatting rule with ;;;@ instead of ;;; you should get the text as well (both of us should get credit if it works)

Comment: I cannot get conditional formatting to work in spite of JvdV's clear instructions! I can get `=IF(ISTEXT(Sheet1!B1),Sheet1!B1,"")` to work in the same fashion as Tom's formula. But I cannot nest the ISNUMBER and ISTEXT functions in an IF ELSE construction. Is that possible?

Comment: I have it working! Conditional formatting `=NOT(ISNUMBER)` and `;;;@`, cell formatting percentage! MUCH appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

A simple conditional formatting example below:

Step **1**

- Rightclick cell `A2` > Format cells > Number > Custom > `0;-0;;@`
- Type a `0` in cell `B2` to test if zeros are no longer displayed

[image]
[image]

Step **2**

- Type `=B2` in cell `A2`
- Type `Test` in cell `B2` to check link and leave it

[image]

Step **3**

- Select cell `A2` > Start > Conditional Formatting > New Rule > Use a Formula > `=ISNUMBER(B2)`
- Format > Number > Percentage
- Type 0,8 in cell `B2` to test.

[image]

The conditional formatting rule will overwrite your custom formatting rule when the rule applies e.g. when cell `B2` is a number!

Comment: I have it working! Conditional formatting `=NOT(ISNUMBER)` and `;;;@`, cell formatting percentage! MUCH appreciated.

Comment: @CDFJ, Nice! As Tom Sharpe mentioned, if this has helped you, you should consider to give both of us credit (upvoting) and mark your question as answered (Tom's answer since you went that route).